# PHP | left join avg query give me Array()

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I'm trying to implement a query within my code that gives me the ability to calculate the average value between the ratings received and the number of ratings per post, and sort posts from the one with the highest rating to to the one with the lowest average rating

[image: db value]

looking at the following table and implementing this query everything works perfectly.

```
   <?php
    $results = $wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT comment_id, avg(meta_value) avg_meta_value
    FROM {$wpdb->prefix}commentmeta 
    
    
    WHERE {$wpdb->prefix}commentmeta.meta_key = 'rating'
    GROUP BY comment_id 
    ORDER BY avg_meta_value desc");
    foreach ($results as $result)
    {
        echo $result->comment_id.'<br>';
    }
```

the problem happens when I want to get a left join with the `comments` table:

[image: db value]

even if the query is correct:

```
        <?php
        $results = $wpdb->get_results("
        SELECT comment_id, avg(meta_value) avg_meta_value
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}commentmeta 
        
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}comments
        ON {$wpdb->prefix}commentmeta.comment_id = {$wpdb->prefix}comments.comment_ID
        
        
        WHERE {$wpdb->prefix}commentmeta.meta_key = 'rating'
        GROUP BY comment_id 
        ORDER BY avg_meta_value desc");

        foreach ($results as $result)
        {
            echo $result->comment_id.'<br>';
        }
        ?>
```

doing the `print_r($ results);` i get: `Array( )`

and I don't understand why, understanding this step is essential for me to make the next join with the post table, so that I can get all the values ​​out, why do I get array ()?

how can i fix it?

.... and

```
var_dump($result); return me `NULL`
```

Comment: Are you sure that you copied code correctly? Because there is: `ON $wpdb->prefix}` and should be `ON {$wpdb->prefix}` - you missed opening brace

Comment: @Choinek i fix this, thanks, but i have same return array()

Comment: you fixed only one place and there are another two places where opening brace is missing

Comment: @Choinek it's not this the problem !!!!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need change line `SELECT comment_id, avg(meta_value) avg_meta_value` to `SELECT comment_id, avg(meta_value) AS avg_meta_value`

Comment: give me often array()